# OOP and new functionality

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I'm going to add new check to existing functionality of class A (method foo()). And I think it would be better to create new class B inherited from A with new private method check() which would be called from foo(). 
From oop point of view it fits open-close principle, but I'm not sure about Liskov substitution principle. 
What do you think? Is it right decision ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with check() you change the class behavior of `foo()` then it perhaps does not fit LSP. If `check()` makes a side-effect, I would create a new method in B like `foo_with_check()`. If it is just to check a pre-condition before `foo()` really does something, you can also do it or consider a pattern like proxy.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I should provide some details. There is an interface 'SomeContract' with method method 'foo()'. Class 'A' is one of possible implementations of this interface. An additional 'check()' will be called before 'A-->foo()' and if it returns 'false' it will be the end of method execution. But the main logic of application uses method 'SomeContract --> foo()' without any knowledge of implementation.

Comment: Actualy, I think 'proxy pattern' could be nice solution of this problem